# Remove an object from a spinner once a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, spinner

So my app has spinners that can be dynamically added and they are being populated from a huge array list of `Course` objects like so

```
courseSpinner = rowView.findViewById(R.id.first_spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<Course> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, courseList);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            courseSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            parentLayout.addView(rowView, parentLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
            allSpinners.add(courseSpinner); //this is an ArrayList of spinners that keeps track of how many spinners exist currently since like mentioned before they can be dynamically added or removed
```

I want to remove the values that are selected after a button is pressed from each newely generated spinner. The button when pressed saves the values to a seperate hash map and deletes all existing spinners but I need to implement some sort of update method that will be called that will repopulate or subtract values from the `courseList` where spinners takle their values from. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your spinner with adapter and list :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_indication, yourList); 
Spinner yourSpinner;
yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
```

your new List created from your old one set it to the adapter like this :

```
yourList = newGeneratedList ;
arrayAdapet.notifyDataSetChanged();
```